# Checkbox value not assigned to Model variable due to onclick event MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Checkbox is not assigning the value to model `value="@Model.ObsDictionay[item.Master_Label_Id.ToString()]"` 
due to javascript function call on onclick

```
onclick="showChildVariables(@item.Master_Label_Id, @item.Label_Name)"
```

VIEW : .cshtml page

```
<div class="form-group">
@foreach(var item in Model.Master_Label)
{

    <input type="checkbox" name="@item.Label_Name" id="@item.Master_Label_Id"                                                            

value="@Model.ObsDictionay[item.Master_Label_Id.ToString()]" checked="="@Model.ObsDictionay[item.Master_Label_Id.ToString()]" onclick="showChildVariables(@item.Master_Label_Id, @item.Label_Name)" />`

    }

</div>


    <script>
    function showChildVariables(chk, div) 
    {
       var chbox = document.getElementById(chk);
      if (chbox.checked) {           
                $(chbox).val(chbox.checked ? true : false)
                document.getElementById(div.name).style.display = "block";
                }
            else
            {
                $(chbox).val(chbox.checked ? true : false)
                var div1 = document.getElementById(div.name);
                var inputs = div1.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; ++i) {

                    if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                        if (inputs[i].checked) {

                            document.getElementById(inputs[i].id).checked = false;

                        }

                    }
                }
    document.getElementById(div.name).style.display = "none";
                }
        }
    </script>
```

How to assign value of checkbox to model variable

Comment: Where's the div with an ID @item.Label_Name?

Comment: Very first, decorate string parameters with quotes before sending to JavaScript function like, `onclick="showChildVariables('@item.Master_Label_Id', '@item.Label_Name')"`.

Comment: On the same .cshtml page
`@foreach (var masterLabel in Model.MasterLabels)
{
 <div class="row portlet solid bordered grey-cararra" style="display:none" id="@masterLabel.Label_Name" name="@masterLabel.Label_Name">
 </div>
}
`